# Does this use of 'as to why' make any sense?

Tags: grammar

Im wondering if this sentence makes sense, characters speaking are both military officers

> "I’m assuming you have been informed that you will be the only officer
> stationed here today?”
>
> "“Yes I have sir, but I was not informed as to why.”

Comment: 'informed as to the reason why' ...'informed as to why' ... 'told the reason why' ... 'told why'. Getting more usual, less formal.

Comment: It's reasonably idiomatic.